# VSTS Bower not found

Tags: build, npm, bower, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are using Visual Studio Team Services for build and deployment of several sites. Some .NET and some are not. All working fine when using the hosted agent. Due to performance issues and long queue times for the hosted agent we need to use our own build agent.
Here comes the problem:
When running the VSTS builds we get an error when running bower:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: bower install
******************************************************************************
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm.cmd install -g bower
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.7.9 C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
Not found bower: null
******************************************************************************
Finishing: bower install
******************************************************************************
```

The problem is that bower is actually in that location:

[image: npm directory]

And here are the actual bower build step:

[image: vsts bower build step]

How can we fix this `Not found bower: null` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are known issues with tools installed into profile folders it has to do with permissions. It's easier to install the tool from an administrative console with the `-g` parameter. And ensure that the central NPM version is added to the service or system's `%path%` environment variable.

Or pass in a specific location by adding additional parameters to the call to npm: `npm install --prefix "$(Agent.WorkFolder)" Bower` Then specify the same location in the Advanced section of the Bower task.

> Bower CLI location: `$(Agent.WorkFolder)\node_modules\`

(You'd need to check the exact location the package is installed to, I'm slightly guessing at the moment ;)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I tried installing from an administrative command prompt with the -g argument but still it installs into the current users AppData folder:
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g bower
C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.7.9 C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower

Comment: It always amazes me how node decides to put stuff somewhere. Are you sure you were running as local administrator?

Comment: Yes, 100 % sure. I triple checked.
Good news is I got it to work by pointing more specif to the local bower lib:
'$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\node_modules\bower\bin\bower' in Bower CLI location.
Now it's the gulp step that fails. Gulp is found, but even thou the gulp dependencies are installed in gulp\node_modules node.js says it can't find one of the modules.

Comment: I tried with your second suggestion, installing into the $(Agent.WorkFolder)\node_modules\ and passing this into the Bower CLI location and it works! Thanks!